# Can we have publication targets defined on the basis of structure groups in Tridion 2009

Tags: tridion, tridion2009

Can we have different publication targets on the basis of structure groups, so if we have two structure groups in my publication [07 Global English] as below:

```
1) My Website
2) My Mobile
```

So whenever user tries to publish the pages/structure group from "My Website" he can see the publication target "Webiste LIVE" and " Website Staging", however same user if he tries to publish from "My Mobile" structure group he will not see the above publication targets instead he will get "Mobile - LIVE" and "Mobile - Staging".

Please suggest if above scenario is possible

Thanks.

Best Regards,

MS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly advice to create a sibling Publication for the Mobile website, next to the default website. Then you don't need to imitate functionality from the content manager, and in particular blueprinting that's standard out of the box.

Comment: Thanks Arjen...Actually earlier we were having child publications...however to avoid extra publication in our Tridion....we moved our mobile setup to our existing publication...and now everything is fine except the publishing rights...we don't want to publish mobile content to our existing website and same vice versa....can this be handled through permission level....or as suggest below from ROB we should have extension

Comment: Publications and Blueprinting is meant to be used for this scenario, using Structure Groups to divide different websites (like mobile and web) is wrong from a SDL Tridion standpoint, which is why you are running into the limitation of not being able to set your Publishing rights.

Comment: Yeah..I am quite aware of these concept of Tridion...any suggestion regarding above issue..can custom page be one of the solution?

Comment: For 2011 you could create a custom Storage Type that changes the storage location based on either Page Metadata or the relative path (Structure Group path). But still, I don't see the value of having one less publication compared to the requirement of having an additional customization.

Answer (score 2):

I concur with Arjen on this one, the scenario you describe should be solved with a separate Publication and BluePrinting rather than trying to hack the Publishing Security model and make it apply to Structure groups instead of Publications (as it is designed).

But next to Rob's answer on trying a UI extension which would hide the non relevant targets based on the Structure Group, I think the only other option is to write a custom resolver which would remove the items from the Publish Transaction.

Now if memory serves me right a custom resolver was already possible in SDL Tridion 2009, but for safety reasons I will indicate this solution for SDL Tridion 2011 only (that I know is working).

A custom Resolver is a class which implements the `IResolver` interface through a `Resolve()` method, some example code of a resolver which removes items will be like:

```cs
public void Resolve(IdentifiableObject item, ResolveInstruction instruction, PublishContext context, Tridion.Collections.ISet<ResolvedItem> resolvedItems)
{
   List<ResolvedItem> itemsToRemove = new List<ResolvedItem>();
   foreach (ResolvedItem resolvedItem in resolvedItems)
   {
      // check if resolved item belongs here
      if (MyResolvedItemCheck(resolvedItem.Item.Id))
      {
         itemsToRemove.Add(resolvedItem);
      }
   }
   // remove all items that we need to discard
   foreach (ResolvedItem itemToRemove in itemsToRemove)
   {
      resolvedItems.Remove(itemToRemove);
   }
}
```

Please note that even though the resolver code is probably easier to write and less expensive than a UI extension is, I still think it is going to be more costly than using Publications and BluePrinting (even if your current SDL Tridion license contains a Blueprint limit which you have reached). You will have to do quite some coding in the `MyResolvedItemCheck()` method and depending on which targets are chosen by the publisher, you might end up with empty Publish Transactions and unclarity for the Editors this way.

Comment: Resolvers have been a public extension points since Tridion 5.3, so they are indeed also possible on Tridion 2009.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can only set Publication Targets on a Publication (someone with more experience than me may say otherwise).

However, you may be able to add all 4 targets to the publication and write an extension which hides targets based on whether the TCM ID of the parent Structure Group matches a configured ID for mobile / website. This would be a hack though and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Ok...in other case any idea or pointer to write extension for above scenario, please note I am looking this solution of Tridion 2009, however in next couple of months we will be moved to Tridion 2011, so solution should compatible to both 2009/2011.

Comment: the UI extension model between 2009 and 2011 is not compatible so that requirement is impossible.